# How can I update a password without entering the password twice?

Tags: centos, password

I effectively have a sticky keyboard (host machine to RDP to vCenter to virtual console), but need to update the password of a VM I am building.

Using the rescue environment CentOS media offers, I can `chroot` to the installed system and run `passwd`, but after typing the password once, I inevitably get an error that the password tokens do not match. (Sometimes typing "passwd" echoes back "passsswwdddd" or similar on the commandline.)

How can I update root's password without needing to enter it twice?

Because I don't know the password, I cannot ssh (which would eliminate the sticky keyboard issue) - hence using a rescue environment and `chroot`.

Comment: Updating the root password without knowing what it is (because of the sticky keyboard) doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @dhag - if I can pass it on the commandline, however, I can fix any stickiness experienced using the remote access options I have available to my lab

Comment: You can run `usermod -p encryptedpassword` . You can use something like `openssl passwd ... ` to generate the encrypted password.

Answer (score 3):

I use this trick in scripts if an interactive prompt has to be used:

```
yourpass='My supersecret password'
$(echo $yourpass; echo $yourpass) | passwd username
```

Basically assign the password to a variable and use that in the following command.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use some form of:

```
# echo "Th3P@ssw0rd" | passwd --stdin theUser
```

assuming your version of the `passwd` binary supports the `--stdin` option.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Mark Plotnick's comment,

```
vi passfile
usermod -p `openssl passwd stdin < passfile` root
rm -f passfile
```

This gives you the opportunity to edit the temporary file and confirm that you have set the password to what you really think it is.  It also keeps the password out of any history, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
# echo 'root:PASSWORD' | chpasswd
```

Please replace PASSWORD with the one you want. It works well for me in Suse Linux.