# Change password without any interaction but can't run commands without error

Tags: password

When logging into my cloud server, I receive this message:

```
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user.
(current) UNIX password:
```

I need to automate the process of entering the current password, and entering the new password after that.

However, every time I try to run a command I get an error saying `WARNING: Your password has expired.\nPassword change required but no TTY available.` (I am connecting via SSH on a Node.js app)

How can I get around this problem? Is there anyway I can run a command without getting that error so I can change the password?

Comment: Related : "Script to change password on linux servers over ssh" using expect - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236699/script-to-change-password-on-linux-servers-over-ssh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update a password without entering the password twice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/190805/how-can-i-update-a-password-without-entering-the-password-twice)

Comment: If the password change prompt comes up on login, it's hard to use `passwd` on the remote before getting hit by the forced change...

Answer (score 1):

You can force `ssh` to allocate a tty with the `-t` switch. Then, it might be possible to just pipe the old and new passwords in. You need to double the `-t` to force allocating a tty even when the stdin of the ssh client is not a terminal:

```
echo -en 'oldpw\nnewpw\nnewpw\n' | ssh -tt somehost true
```